# Hide rows in one worksheet based on a cell value in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I know this question has been asked ad nauseum and I'm sorry to add to the mix, but I've been through many and varied posts to try to find the solution, and my code is just not doing anything.  I have a drop down box in Worksheet tab cell 49 that has 3 options: Hybrid, Online, and Residential.  I'd like when a person selects Hybrid or Online rows 37-63 in my Memo tab to be hidden.  When a person selects Residential rows 37-63 are visible.  I thought this would easy, but no matter what I do, nothing is happening.  I have this in the specific "Memo" tab code, not within the module.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the code I have written.  Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   For a = 37 To 63
      If Worksheets("Worksheet").Cell(C49).Value <> "Residential" Then
         Worksheets("Memo").Rows(a).Hidden = True
      ElseIf Worksheets("Worksheet").Cell(C49).Value = "Residential" Then
             Worksheets("Memo").Rows(a).Hidden = False
      End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Surprised your research hasn't flagged up syntax errors - should be `Range("C49")`. Also restrict the code to changes to that cell otherwise it will fire any time any cell is changed.

Comment: Can shorten to `Worksheets("Memo").Rows(a).Hidden = (Worksheets("Worksheet").range("C49").Value <> "Residential")`

Comment: Also you don't need a loop, do it all in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Upshot of various comments is I think that your code can be reduced to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If intersect(Target,range("C49")) is nothing Then Exit Sub

Worksheets("Memo").Rows("37:63").Hidden = (Range("C49").Value <> "Residential")

End Sub
```

Edit: updated as per @Pᴇʜ's comment.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - sorry, don't follow, surely both `Target` and `Range("C49")` are on the same sheet (the one with the event code)? How can it not be the active sheet if the code is triggered?

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong. `Range("C49")` does not point to `ActiveSheet` (as I thought) if it is within a sheets scope (it only does when written in a module). Obviously it refers alwas to the sheet's scope `Me` by default. • Otherwise it could happen that another sheet is active and the event is triggered by and VBA action that updates a value in the sheet with the event. • I removed my comments